# NSolve results in imaginary solutions for Physical System

Tags: numerics

I have the following function:

```
F[z_,V_] := (h*c*Pi^2*A)/(240*z^4) + eps*A/(2*z^2)*V^2 - k*(g - z);
```

It's a pyhsical force that depends on the voltage "V" and the gap "g". "z" is the deflection of the object after applying the voltage "V".

And I would like to numerically solve the following system of equations:

```
h =  6.62607015*10^(\[Minus]34);
c =  299792458 ;
eps = 8.8541878128*10^(\[Minus]12);
w = 1*10^-6;
l = 10*10^-6;
A = w*l;
t =  100*10^-9;
i = w*t^3/12;
e =  120*10^9;
k =  3*e*i/l^3;
g = 50*10^-9;
sol = NSolve[{F[z, V] == 0 , D[F[z, V], z] == 0 } , {V, z}]
```

The result is:

```
{{V -> -0.548103 - 0.668107 I, 
  z -> -5.17747*10^-8 - 4.12381*10^-8 I}, {V -> -0.548103 + 
    0.668107 I, 
  z -> -5.17747*10^-8 + 4.12381*10^-8 I}, {V -> 0.548103 - 0.668107 I,
   z -> -5.17747*10^-8 + 4.12381*10^-8 I}, {V -> 
   0.548103 + 0.668107 I, 
  z -> -5.17747*10^-8 - 4.12381*10^-8 I}, {V -> 0.69165 - 0.342071 I, 
  z -> 2.88007*10^-8 - 6.63079*10^-8 I}, {V -> 0.69165 + 0.342071 I, 
  z -> 2.88007*10^-8 + 6.63079*10^-8 I}, {V -> -0.69165 - 0.342071 I, 
  z -> 2.88007*10^-8 + 6.63079*10^-8 I}, {V -> -0.69165 + 0.342071 I, 
  z -> 2.88007*10^-8 - 6.63079*10^-8 I}, {V -> 0. - 0.64675 I, 
  z -> 7.92814*10^-8}, {V -> 0. + 0.64675 I, z -> 7.92814*10^-8}}
```

As you can see all values are imaginary ! This should not be the case, since it is a pyhsical system, the values should be real and positive.

I have notices that *if I increase the gap anything above 130nm* *it works*, and I get one solution that is real and positive for every gap.

**I was therefore wondering, if this is a numeric issue for the lower gap values, and how I could solve it ?**

Many thanks.

Comment: Should not the function be `F[z_,V_]` and not `F[z_]`? This is how you are calling it.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for spotting that typo

Comment: This might simply require input that is higher precision than `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your comment. How would you test this ?

Comment: I'd give higher precision (or perhaps exact) input and try adjusting the `WorkingPrecision` option in `NSolve`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Okay, many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add conditions and domain to `Solve` command:

```
Solve[F[z] == 0 && D[F[z], z] == 0 && h > 0 && c > 0 && eps > 0 && A > 0, {V, z}, Reals]
```

This gives `ConditionalExpressions`:

[image]

So, except of all the variables shoud be positive, we have another condition on `k`, or we can rewrite it in terms of `g`:

```
g^5 > (625*c*h*l*Pi^2)/(3072*e*t^3)
```

and substituting your numnerical values one can find that

```
g^5 > 3.32395*10^-20
```

or

```
g > 0.000127154
```

the result you mentioned in question.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not know that one could specify domains too .

Comment: Glad to help you!